# How do I clone Windows 7 offline?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone

I have an offline Windows 7 PC whose drive is failing. Rather than reinstalling, which takes some time for this PC, I'd like to clone it.

Are there any tools or methods to reliably clone a drive with all of its partitions (and even from HDD to SSD) without having to reactivate Windows 7 (32, Ult) online?

Comment: Simply cloning or changing a disk should not trigger reactivation at all. Any disk partitioning or cloning tool should do the job.

Comment: If the drive is failing, there's a risk your cloned image may be corrupt, which gets you no further forward. You might be better backing up (you should already have done this), and do a clean install onto a new HDD.

Comment: The issue arose suddenly yesterday when after a power outage the PC began to hang on boot with a warning about a SMART failure of the boot drive. With F1 the OS loads without problems but whether the outage messed up the SMART attributes or something is actually wrong, I don't intend to find out.

Reinstalling the PC would require a tedious amount of work because it is highly configured.

With disk scans coming back good, I am confident that a clone will be structurally healthy. I am not worried. Either way, I need to change the drive and I'd like to try the easy way first: clone.